# How to remove X-Content-Type-Options header parameter from Oracle Weblogic Server response header

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, weblogic11g

When opening my web page in **IE11**, I'm seeing javascript files are blocked from executing with a message "Script from **https://actual url goes here/jquery-1.8.3.min.js** was blocked due to mime type mismatch". When I googled I found some posts which tells the response header **X-content-type-options** causing the issue. My server is Oracle Weblogic Server 11g. Is there any way to remove this header parameter from Weblogic server response?
[image: Please see the screenshot for details]

Is the header param can be confiugured from browser setting?

Any suggestions on this would really helpful.